# Adding Recent EIP's to Custom Blockchain

Tags: blockchain, parity

I have a custom blockchain running on Parity 2.3.8.  My question is do the recent EIP additions (https://coinswitch.co/news/ethereum-hard-fork-jan-19-know-everything-about-3-upcoming-eth-hard-forks) *automatically* become part of my new blockchain or is it necessary to manually add them each?

Related question: do they all get added under the `params` section of my chain specificaion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is defined by [Chain Specification](https://wiki.parity.io/Chain-specification).  Note all these `eipXXXTransition` parameters.  They define what moment these EIPs will be enabled in your blockchain.  You may probably set all of them to zero to enable them from the very beginning.